# Adding Filter over MSK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

I am using the flow where the data from HVR is passed to MSK and then it is consumed by Lambda for processing and sent to SQS.
HVR->MSK->lambda->SQS

I can't apply any filter near HVR as it feeds data to multiple places.

So, is there any way that I can apply some filter in MSK, so that only required meassages(records) get passed as input to lambda.

I am aware of the trigger filter available for lambda, but as I am polling from msk from inside the lambda code I am not using the trigger filter.

Comment: Kafka currently has no mechanism to push filters too it although it is being discussed in the community. MSK runs vanilla Kafka and hence they can't support filters.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the documentation, there is now an `Additional Setting` for `Filter criteria` in an MSK trigger, where you can set some limited filter types. See [amazon's documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-msk-smak) for more clarity on how to write a filter.

My recent foray into this area has me building a relatively straightforward filter for a payload that looks like this:

```bash
{
\"key\": \"90e9b686-edfd-4b22-b377-a88bdeb2560d::asdf32sdfa\", 
\"value\": {
    \"data\": {
                \"id\": \"zxcv-234r0rkl\", 
                \"direction\": \"inbound\", 
                \"type\": \"blah.blah.blah\"
        }
    }
}
```

In the AWS lambda MSK trigger console, I added the following filter criteria to generate a valid json filter:

```bash
{"value" : { "data" : { "type" : [ "blah.blah.blah" ] }}}"
```

The documentation is pretty wretched, but this [blog post](https://dev.to/aws-builders/trigger-lambda-functions-with-event-filtering-2pnb) was helpful in at least understanding that the UI might stink, and the docs aren't great, but the functionality is there.

Happy filtering!